# Is there a name for this expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

Is there a commonly accepted name for expression of the form:
$$
\sqrt{\sum_i V^2_i + \sum_i\sum_{j\neq i}\kappa_{ij}V_i V_j}
$$
where V is a vector and $\kappa$ is a matrix of weights.

sorry if my notation is incorrect

Comment: This is not an equation at all; equations have an equals sign.

Comment: I changed the "equation" to "expression", if you don't mind..

Comment: I removed the [tag:numerical-linear-algebra] tag since it's not relevant to the question. Please read the tag description before applying a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote by $K$ the matrix with $1$s on the diagonal which is otherwise equal to $\kappa$. Assuming $K$ is positive definite, this quantity is called the $K$ norm of the vector $V$. If $K$ is positive semidefinite then it is called the $K$ seminorm of $V$. If $K$ is not even positive semidefinite then this quantity has no special name to my knowledge.

This quantity can also be written as $\sqrt{V^T K V}$.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: And in any case. using $K$ it can be written as $\sqrt{V^TKV}$. The given quantity is only defined if $K$ is positive definite on the space where $V$ comes from.

Comment: @RobertMah Welcome to math.stackexchange. If you agree with the answer, it is a common practice to accept it by clicking on "accept answer".

Comment: @PeterFranek There's a 15 minute wait time afaik.

Comment: @AlexR It could be defined for only a subset of the space $V$ comes from. It is also *defined* when $K$ is only positive semidefinite (in which case it is sometimes zero even when $V$ is not zero, but the argument to the square root is never negative). But yes, if $K$ is not positive definite then the given quantity should not be called a norm.

Comment: @Ian my bad about semidefiniteness. About the definedness: that subset will always be a subspace (in the finite-dimensional case), so I'd call that subspace "the space where $V$ comes from".

Comment: @AlexR Is that true in the absence of symmetry? (I agree with you, and did not notice your point, in the symmetric case.)

Comment: @Ian in that case you can symmetrize $K$, $K' = \frac12(K+K^T)$ and call it the $K'$ (semi-)norm on said subspace.